# Embedding Typeform into angular app doesn't work?

Tags: angular, typescript, embedding, typeform

I'm embedding a Typeform in Angular component according to [SDK](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/).

Component template has div:

```
<div
    #embedTypeform
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
></div>
```

And I'm using SDK in AfterViewInit:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as typeformEmbed from '@typeform/embed';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-answer-form',
  templateUrl: './answer-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./answer-form.component.css']
})
export class AnswerFormComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('embedTypeform', { static: false }) embedElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.embedElement) {
      console.log(this.embedElement);
      typeformEmbed.makeWidget(
        this.embedElement,
        'https://xxx.typeform.com/to/xxx',
        {
          hideHeaders: true,
          hideFooter: true,
          opacity: 75,
          buttonText: 'Take the survey!',
          onSubmit: () => {
            console.log('Typeform successfully submitted');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }

}
```

And in effect I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that the first parameter should be the DOM element, not the Angular ElementRef. try with `this.embedElement.nativeElement` instead. Source for my guess: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typeform/embed

Comment: True, indeed this was the problem. Thanks a million!